# Autofac does not resolve controller action parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autofac

I have an abstract class called LanguageBase.

I have also have a derived class called Language (do not worry about WHY I do this - there is a valid use case for this but falls outside the scope of this discussion).

In my ASP.Net MVC application, I have a controller for which some of the action methods take LanguageBase as a parameter.  During runtime, Autofac must resolve this to Language.

In Global.asax, I have the following method to register my types and create my container:

```
 private void RegisterTypes()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html
        builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly).PropertiesAutowired();

        builder.RegisterType<Language>().As<LanguageBase>();

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));

    }
```

However, during runtime, I receive this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Cannot create an abstract class.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an
>   abstract class.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
>   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean
>   publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +113
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +206    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +11    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
>   +197
>
> [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class. Object type
>   'Visia.PartyRoles.Generic.IDomain.LanguageBase'.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.CreateModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
>   +233    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindComplexModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +531
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) +330
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) +331
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +105
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +743
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +14
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +343
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +25
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +465
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__14(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) +18
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +20
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +374
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +16
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +52 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +30
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +128
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +384
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +103    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Am I missing something?

**UPDATE**

Here is my controller code...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Visia.MasterData.Banking.DAL;
using Visia.PartyRoles.Core.Banking.IDataServices;
using Visia.PartyRoles.Generic.IDomain;

namespace Visia.CrediScan.UI.Views
{
    public class LanguagesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly QueryBase _query;
        private readonly CommandBase _command;

        public LanguagesController(QueryBase query, CommandBase command)
        {
            if (query == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(query));
            if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(command));
            _query = query;
            _command = command;
        }

        // GET: /Languages/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(long? id, long CountryId)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var language = _query.GetLanguage((long)id);
            if (language == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.CountryId = CountryId;
            return View(language);
        }

        // POST: /Languages/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(LanguageBase language, long CountryId)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                language.CountryId = CountryId.ToString();
                _command.Update(language);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", new { CountryId = CountryId });
            }
            return View(language);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant code in the controller?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Controller code added...

Comment: Why are you injecting `LanguageBase` into the `Edit` method instead of the constructor?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Model binding needs to take place against the language parameter of the action method.

Comment: I don't think the issue is related to Autofac. It's the MVC framework that is responsible for creating the `LanguageBase` object here. And it doesn't know how because it is abstract. Is there a reason why you don't use `Language` here?

Comment: @YacoubMassad What I want to achieve is to achieve absolute loose coupling, and as such do not want to pass the concrete class Language as a parameter.  As such, the expectation is that Autofac will instantiate an instance of the concrete Language class during runtime, in stead of the abstract LanguageBase class.

Comment: Are `LanguageBase` and `Language` simple property bags? Or do they contain behavior?

Comment: @YacoubMassad No, it is not simple property bags.  There are different possible implementations of LanguageBase based on the data access mechanism applied, and I need to swop it out as required using DI.  Specifically, certain properties have, for instance, serialization behaviour that can change depending on the storage mechanism.  I can also have different implementations for, for instance, relational db's and no-sql db's.

Comment: Can you shed more light on these classes and the kind of behavior that they have?

Comment: This is not an Autofac issue - it has no control over how MVC calls its controllers. You can't use abstract classes as MVC action method params out of the box. If you really want to do that, you will need to write a custom binder.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Autofac, as far as I can see, and is an MVC issue. Could you edit your question as it will make it a lot clearer.

Comment: You can probably use a custom Model Binder (via `IModelBinder`) to solve your issue. However, I think that you might be able to design it better to solve your issue. I don't think that you should have an object with behavior as a parameter in your controller actions.

Comment: @SlavaAsipenko I reckoned that I would have to write a custom binder for that.  I just wanted to make sure that I didn't miss some out-of-the-box ability before I started.

Comment: @YacoubMassad You are probably right - I should rather make use of a viewmodel.  It feels awfully trivial, through.

Comment: I disagree strongly with everyone stating that this issue does not relate to Autofac.  I am attempting to achieve something very specific using Autofac, namely injecting a dependency into an action controller.  Dependency injection is not a function of the model binder interface.  Model binding, as the name suggests, is the purpose of the model binder.  If I have to write a custom model binder to allow Autofac to do this, then the issue still mainly pertains to how to achieve this outcome using Autofac.

Comment: @CraftBeerHipsterDude take a look at action injection: http://aspnetmvc.readthedocs.org/projects/mvc/en/latest/controllers/dependency-injection.html#action-injection-with-fromservices 
Looks like decorating  params with ```[DataServices]``` allows for action injection; I was only aware of constructor injection support in MVC

Comment: @SlavaAsipenko That is definitely more in line with what I had in mind.  I am unfortunately still working of an older version of Asp.Net MVC which does not yet support this.

Answer (score 2):

You issue is not related to Autofac. It is the MVC framework that is responsible for creating the arguments for the action method based on the data from the request.

Although you can create a custom Model Binder (via the [`IModelBinder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.imodelbinder(v=vs.118).aspx) interface) to solve your issue, I recommend that you don't have action parameters that contain behavior.

Instead, create a simple model (e.g. `Language`) that contains only data and use it as an action parameter. And have another service (e.g. `ILanguageService`) that contains that behavior that you might want to vary using DI. Such service would be injected into the constructor of the controller.

---

Take a look at [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/). The way I see it, the action methods are at the boundary of your application. So your action parameters shouldn't be Object Oriented, i.e., they shouldn't contain behavior. They should be simple data objects. Then you can use another service to translate the simple data object to some object that is Object Oriented (contains behavior). Such service would then be injected through the constructor (and thus Autofac can handle it).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it still requires your lightweight / dto / viewmodel Language object to be mapped to an instantiation of the abstract class LanguageBase, forcing the use of the servicelocator anti-pattern to create such an instance.  The services that I am calling from my controller method is black box, meaning I can't handle this mapping from inside those services.

Comment: Why do you need this ViewModel to inherit from `LanguageBase`? And why do you need to use the service locator in this case? Can you elaborate?

Comment: The viewmodel does not have to inherit from LanguageBase, but since My Data Access component takes a LanguageBase object as parameter, I do need to create an instance of LanguageBase to pass into my data access component. It thus follows that I would have to create a LanguageBase derived instance (using servicelocator) and map the values of the viewmodel object to the instance.

Comment: You don't have to use a service locator. Inject some `IConverter<ViewModel, LanguageBase>` service into the constructor of the controller, and this service can convert your view model to a derived class of `LanguageBase`.

Comment: I guess that is what I will end up doing.  However, it still feels as though action method injection is something which should be supported by the Autofac MVC library.